# CUDALink not working - Mathematica 12.1

Tags: cudalink

I am trying out some CUDA code on a Windows 10 machine  with a Nvidia RTX 3060 and can't even get the installation working, as per the debug output below :

I read the various documentation and help but to no avail. I have the latest NVIDIA CUDA and drivers.  System environment variables point to the appropriate .dll and librairies.

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]
CUDAQ[]
CUDADriverVersion[]
CUDAResourcesInstall[]
CUDAResourcesInformation[]
SystemInformation[]
```

[image: output]

Comment: 12.1 is too old. You can use my notebook to verify it is all good: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/13f45cd5-6d93-4bab-8c82-e0e08d824984

Comment: It might be the older toolkit version you've got doesn't work with that GPU. Try `CUDAToolkitCompatibilityInformation[]`. Apparently toolkit 11.1 introduced support for 30 series cards, [see here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-11-1-introduces-support-rtx-30-series/) and Mathematica's automatically installed toolkit is deprecated - they now expect you to install the right toolkit yourself.

Comment: Also my notebook above has an issue in 13.2, it activates OpenCL too, yet it is buggy. Remove Needs["OpenCLLink`"], it is not needed anyway.

Comment: @flinty where can I find the appropriate toolkit paclet ?

Comment: @Gagle I don't know if there is one any more - I think you have to install the toolkit from nvidia these days.

Comment: @flinty ok that well I already updated the CUDAToolkit to the latest version found on the Nvidia website.  And thanks to your comment I was able to investigate further and notice that the Mathematica CUDALink files are still on v10.  Don't know what to do next but it's progress I guess.

Comment: Cuda SDK is not toolkit.

Comment: Cuda sdk 12.0 is not supported yet. You need to install 11.8. https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2730946 directs links: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive